# how to plot two barh in one axis in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I need something like this:
[image]
demo data:

```
bottom10
Out[12]: 
0   -9.823127e+08
1   -8.069270e+08
2   -6.030317e+08
3   -5.709379e+08
4   -5.224355e+08
5   -4.755464e+08
6   -4.095561e+08
7   -3.989287e+08
8   -3.885740e+08
9   -3.691114e+08
Name: amount, dtype: float64

top10
Out[13]: 
0    9.360520e+08
1    9.078776e+08
2    6.603838e+08
3    4.967611e+08
4    4.409362e+08
5    3.914972e+08
6    3.547471e+08
7    3.538894e+08
8    3.368558e+08
9    3.189895e+08
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

The same question for matplotlib is here:[how to plot two barh in one axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736806/how-to-plot-two-barh-in-one-axis)
But there is not any ax.twiny() in pyqtgraph. Any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a Widgets "**BarGraphItem**",which not written in offical documentation([PyQtGraph’s Widgets List](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/index.html#api-widgets)). It can "**rotate**()" to make barh like matplotlib. It's not perfect but works!
[image]

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bottom10 = pd.DataFrame({'amount':-np.sort(np.random.rand(10))})
top10 = pd.DataFrame({'amount':np.sort(np.random.rand(10))[::-1]})
maxtick=max(top10.amount.max(),-bottom10.amount.min())*1.3

win1 = pg.plot()  
axtop=pg.BarGraphItem(x=range(len(top10)),height=top10.amount,width=0.6,brush='r')
axtop.rotate(-90)
win1.addItem(axtop)
axbt=pg.BarGraphItem(x=range(len(top10)),height=-bottom10.amount,y0=maxtick+bottom10.amount,width=0.6,brush='g')
axbt.rotate(-90)
win1.addItem(axbt)
```